# How to add arithmetic variables in a script

Tags: shell, shell-script, arithmetic

I want to accumulate the line size of a number of files contained in a folder. I have written the following script:

```
let a=0
let num=0
for i in folder/*
do
        num=`cat $i | wc -l`
        a=$a+$num
done
echo $a
```

What i am geting at the end of the script is 123+234+432+... and not the result of the arithmetic operation of addition.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Your arithmetic evaluation syntax is wrong. Use any of the following (the first is extremely portable but slow, the second is POSIX and portable except to the Bourne shell and earlier versions of the Almquist shell, the last three require `ksh`, `bash` or `zsh`):

```
a=`expr "$a" + "$num"`

a=$(($a+$num))

((a=a+num))

let a=a+num

((a+=num))
```

Or you can just skip the entire `for` loop and just do:

```
wc -l folder/*
```

Or, if you only want the total:

```
cat folder/* | wc -l
```

Or with zsh and its `mult_ios` option:

```
wc -l < folder/*
```

Comment: No need for the `$` inside `((...))`. `a=$((a+num))` is already fine.

Comment: if a variable is not set or having null value, would this work, if no any other way to handle that.

Comment: `$((a+num))` is slightly faster than `$(($a+$num))`, tested in bash.

Answer (score 7):

you can also use this code

```
    a=`expr $a + $num`
    echo $a
```

and **MAKE SURE THAT THERE IS A SPACE ON BOTH SIDES OF + IN "$a + $num"**

Comment: always give space on both sides of operator when using expr command for calculation.

Answer (score 4):

The answer needs to specify in **which shell** the code is valid.
For instance in the bourne Shell (`sh`) only the following instructions are valid:

```
a=$((a+num))
a=$(($a+$num))
```

while the other possibilities listed by @manatwork may be valid in bourne *again* shell (`bash`)

Answer (score 2):

You could declare the type of variable first:

```
    declare -i a=0
    declare -i num=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, previous edit was for a different post. Here, just a small modification to the original script:

```
let a=0
let num=0
for i in folder/*
do
        num=`cat $i | wc -l`
        a=$(echo $a+$num|bc)
done
echo $a
```

Comment: Voted down, as the answer doesn't appear to address the question.

Comment: Sorry guys, now corrected

Answer (score -1):

i make it like this

```
MY_VARIABLE=$((num1+num2))
```

Comment: This adds nothing to what has already been said.

Comment: it is the brief answer