# Shell script runs with bash but not with sh. Why and how to fix it?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, error-handling

I have the following shell script that sums up all the arguments passed to it (space separated):

```
sum=0
for arg in "$@"; do
    (( sum += arg ))
done
echo $sum
```

I have saved it as `SumAll.sh`. So, its supposed to function as follows:

```
sh SumAll.sh 2 4 6 8
20
```

or

```
bash SumAll.sh 1 -2 3 -3
-1
```

Both work on my local machine (MacBook), but when I try the same in a linux server, running the script with `bash` works, but with `sh` does not work. I get the following error:

```
sum: '+=': No such file or directory
sum: arg: No such file or directory
```

Why is that? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add arithmetic variables in a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55069/how-to-add-arithmetic-variables-in-a-script)

Comment: `(( arith expr ))` is a `ksh88` extension and not supported by many shells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arithmetic evaluation with `(( ... ))` is an extension to the standard POSIX shell syntax that `bash` implements.  Most `sh` shells would not understand that syntax.

Use an arithmetic substitution instead: `sum=$(( sum + arg ))`

In a shell that does not implement the non-standard `(( ... ))`, your `(( sum += arg ))` command will be interpreted as a nested subshell, calling the command `sum` with the two arguments `+=` and `arg`.

On macOS, `sum` is a utility that calculates checksums of files (see `man sum`), and the files `+=` and `arg` can not be found (which is why you get that particular error).

Comment: The follow-on question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/250913/5132 .  The Bourne Again, Z, and Korn shells all have `((…))`.  The Almquist and Bourne shells, the former being the most likely `sh` given its use on Debian and its derivatives, do not. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149916/5132

Comment: @JdeBP and that comment is the correct answer for "why is that" - linux default `sh` is most likely symlink to `dash`

Answer (score 2):

Use [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Example using your script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
sum=0
for arg in "$@"; do
    (( sum += arg ))
done
echo $sum
```

result:

```
$ shellcheck myscript

Line 6:
echo $sum
     ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
echo "$sum"
```

As you can see, this works, but if you use sh like you did previously:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
sum=0
for arg in "$@"; do
    (( sum += arg ))
done
echo $sum
```

result:

```
$ shellcheck myscript

Line 4:
    (( sum += arg ))
    ^-- SC2039: In POSIX sh, standalone ((..)) is undefined.

Line 6:
echo $sum
     ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
echo "$sum"
```

This doesn't work here, because of the error `SC2039` (which is the first one in this instance).

While obvious, you need to remember that `sh` and `bash` have some difference in syntax. So that's the main reason it doesn't work. (as @kusalananda detailed in his answer)

You should also use the `-x` or debug flag more often, so you can see what and at which moment your script fail.

For more infos and tips on bash and shell scripting, i recommend:

-[Bash's Unofficial Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/)

-[Bash Bible](https://github.com/dylanaraps/pure-bash-bible)